# Java Rest API on Vert.x

Tags: java, rest, api, vert.x

I'm developing REST API service based on Java and Eclipse Vert.x framework. I didn't use Vert.x previously and I faced with such architectural issue. When I need to implement API for few REST resources (for example, `users` and `products`) should I created separate verticles for each resource?

For instance, when I implemented some REST API using Jersey, I created separate resource classes (for our example it could be `UsersResource` and `ProductsResource` classes). In each class I implemented allowed actions (e.g. CRUD operations) and mapped them to REST methods (like GET, POST, etc). But should I implement it in a similar way when I work with Vert.x (create `UsersVerticle` and `ProductsVerticle`), or does it have some other ideological approach?

Comment: I have no experience with Vert.x, but I am interested in it. I thought it was a gateway application. In that case it would be used for service registration/load balancing and aggregation. So, the underlying services would have the same verticals. If it is very good at aggregation then in the case that it makes sense to provide an API that gives results from multiple underlying services then Vert.x should be able to combine asynchronous results from individual vertical services. Again, no experience with Vert.x directly. This question is too broad for this forum. Perhaps a google group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, it depends. Generally, the Router/web server would be a single verticle and the implementation code would be in one or more other verticles. A better approach is to use the Service Proxy capability though. This will allow you to more clearly define your API without as much hand wiring of event bus endpoints. Have a look at https://github.com/rhoar-shootout/rhoar-vertx to see a good example.

EDIT - Things have moved on and changed

Now, there are better tools for using Service Proxies with Vert.x Router. I would recommend using the new [OpenAPI3RouterFactory](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web-api-contract/java/) along with an [OpenAPI](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/about/) specification file. In conjunction with the [vertx-starter](https://github.com/pmlopes/vertx-starter) tool, you can generate the Service Proxies AND the OpenAPI3Router code from the specification file.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to create a single `RestAPIVerticle` and use a `Router` within that `Verticle` to setup your routes. You can however modularize your routes by creating classes and package routes for specific tasks together. But always use a dedicated Router/Routes for your RestAPIVerticle.

Sharing routes or handlers across multiple Verticles is a bad idea because it violates the thread safety model of Vert.x. Most handlers are not (and must not be) threadsafe and thus you could get into trouble when sharing routes or handlers between Verticles.

If you need to handle more requests you can easily deploy another instance of your Verticle.

I use the process described for Gentics Mesh which uses Vert.x to provide a REST API. I summarized the workflow here:
https://getmesh.io/docs/beta/contributing.html#_big_picture

Sources are also on Github.

Another option is of course to generate your implementation from an REST specification (Contract driven design). I think there is an article on the Vert.x blog which describes this process.